# Fancontrol HP laptop /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules in

Tags: elementary-os, fan, sensors

I'm trying to get fancontrol working my HP Spectre 13 3000ed, because the fans are either off or annoyingly noisy. I followed this tutorial: [How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

But I got stuck with /usr/sbin/pwmconfig:

> There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

I tried to resolve that with the information here: [pwmconfig](https://iandw.net/2014/10/12/fancontrol-under-ubuntu-14-04-resolving-usrsbinpwmconfig-there-are-no-pwm-capable-sensor-modules-installed/)

That did not work.
Please help me, the noise is killing me!

Below my terminal output on sensors & sudo sensors-detect & sudo pwmconfig.

I'm on elementary OS Freya based on Ubuntu 14.04.

[Terminal output](http://pastebin.com/L2Z4Lpu9)

Comment: The output seems to be saying that you're out of luck. It also mentions "*Note that many motherboards do not have pwm circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.*" What sort of answer are you expecting?

Comment: @Anko oke thanks I just hoped that there was a workaround.

Comment: Buying a quieter fan might be a functional workaround. Good luck!